# Do we need to clarify we have no afilliation with Musk's companies?

Tags: discussion

From time to time I see a question that appears to have come from someone who thinks they are asking a question of SpaceX rather than a StackExchange community. Is there anything we can do to avoid such people wasting their time, and ours?

This is the most recent: [Long(r) time perspective](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33589/longr-time-perspective)

Comment: I'm not sure where would be the best place for it. Maybe the Tour? It would have to be a feature request.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so. There's tons of ways to note that it isn't official, and we don't have a URL that would indicate this is the fact. Some times people post such things anyways, but I don't think adding a disclaimer anywhere would change that fact in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking from experience, people wouldn't read it anyways. It's not as big a deal here as it is in other places, though. You can always reword a decent question (via edits) into ones that aren't conversational but answerable (provided it's not Too Broad like the example). At least he did take that advice and [break his question up](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33600/does-spacex-plan-to-enhance-change-genome-of-colonists-to-speed-up-adaptation-pr)